# Increment in a feature (karate)

Tags: karate

I need to create kittens like in this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/calltable/call-table.feature. But I need to increment names like `name1 and age1, name2 and age2, name3 and age3...` and not put the names and ages in the table kittens. How I can do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `call` a feature using a JSON array - which will call the feature in a loop, within the called feature, you have access to a special built-in variable called `__loop`.

Refer to the documentation here: [Built in variables for `call`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#built-in-variables-for-call)

So you can do things like `{ name: "#('Name' + __loop)" }`

(edit): apparently the above was too confusing :/, let me try another suggestion. Please look at this example: [call-dynamic-json.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/calldynamic/call-dynamic-json.feature)

You can see how you can have 100% control of creating kittens in a loop instead of using a `table`. All the best :P

Comment: wow, thanks for your very quick reply. Sorry, but I can't understand well: in feature A I need to increment kittens and call feature B (createOneKitten.feature). In feature A how I can stop the loop. I mean if I want to create 5 kittens how I can put this?

Comment: edited my answer, I think this is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: great, it works with call-dynamic-json.feature. But After in Feature A I need to use `Kit1`. How I can extract it from `* def kittensFn =
"""
function(count) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
    out.push({ name: 'Kit' + i });
  }
  return out;
}
"""` Thanks

Comment: look it returns a JSON array right, so just access it by index `* def first = kittens[0]` - please talk to someone who understands JS before asking these questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice `return out`. It works, thank you very much